# Как прописать manifest при сборке в .exe (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при сборке .py в .exe прописать manifest или добавить подпись, чтобы исполняемый файл мог работать с своими файлами в C:\Program Files (x86) ?

а также антивирус не думал, что это троян)

и чтобы отображалась инфо о файле здесь:
[image: https://yadi.sk/i/2R-5xobZ3VTn8U]

Comment: Прикольная ава бро! =)

Comment: ______ пасиба ))

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html#windows-specific-options) есть про манифест и версию.

```
--version-file FILE
    add a version resource from FILE to the exe
--manifest <FILE or XML>
    add manifest FILE or XML to the exe
```

Comment: пробовал уже по всякому, но увы не выходит - беда в том, что приложению нужно сохранять данные в отдельном файле, а когда вся директория находится в C:\Program Files (x86)\  то просто все крашится. Вероятно неправильно манифест составляю.  Может есть готовые примеры manifest'a и version-file?

Comment: а что там за код такой, что нужно писать в програм файлес? может лучше сделать в appdata ?

Comment: хмм спасибо, сразу и не подумал    [ссылка на код](https://github.com/samwl/daily_bing_wallpapper/blob/master/dw.py) ,но с манифестами все равно хочу разобраться..